# Add stdout of subprocess to JSON report if test case fails

Tags: python, pytest, test-reporting

I'm investigating methods of adding to the JSON report generated by either `pytest-json` or `pytest-json-report`: I'm not hung up on either plugin.  So far, I've done the bulk of my evaluation using `pytest-json`.  So, for example, the JSON object has this for a test case

```
{
    "name": "fixture_test.py::test_failure1",
    "duration": 0.0012421607971191406,
    "run_index": 2,
    "setup": {
        "name": "setup",
        "duration": 0.00011181831359863281,
        "outcome": "passed"
    },
    "call": {
        "name": "call",
        "duration": 0.0008759498596191406,
        "outcome": "failed",
        "longrepr": "def test_failure1():\n>       assert 3 == 4, \"3 always equals 3\"\nE       AssertionError: 3 always equals 3\nE       assert 3 == 4\n\nfixture_test.py:19: AssertionError"
    },
    "teardown": {
        "name": "teardown",
        "duration": 0.00014257431030273438,
        "outcome": "passed"
    },
    "outcome": "failed"
}
```

This is from experiments I'm trying.  In practice, some of the test cases are done by spawning a sub-process via `Popen` and the assert is that a certain string appears in the stdout.  In the event that the test case fails, I need to add a key/value to the *call* dictionary which contains the stdout of that subprocess.  I have tried in vain thus far to find the correct fixture or apparatus to accomplish this.  It seems that the  [pytest_exception_interact](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_exception_interact) may be the way to go, but drilling into the JSON structure has thus far eluded me.  All I need to do is add/modify the JSON structure at the point of an error.  It seems that [pytest_runtest_call](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_call) is too heavy handed.

Alternatively, is there a means of altering the value of `longrepr` in the above?  I've been unable to find the correct way of doing either of these and it's time to ask.

Comment: You can convert a JSON object into a Python dictionary, and they (dictionaries) coulf be modified and then turned back into JSON. Seems relatively straightforward — what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @martineau I have considered that.  The detractor I have at this point with that approach is that I don't want to store _somewhere_ the stdout until after the test.  I'd like a means of directly adding to the JSON object while the test is running rather than post processing.  Unless, there's a clean way of doing what you're suggesting in the test.

Comment: Unless one of those two plugins supports it some way, you'll have to do post-processing.

Comment: @martineau actually, I did find the answer.  Thankfully, I'm not hung up on `pytest-json`.  It seems that plugin isn't in active development (the developer of `pytest-json-report` says so).  I'm foregoing investigation and accepting his word.  Anyway, `pytest-json-report` places stuff captured in `stdout`, `stderr`, etc. into the JSON report.  That's what I need.  I guess I'll be answering my own question.

Comment: Andrew: That's good to hear. You can post an answer to your own question (and accept it) — and doing so could help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2):

As it would appear, the `pytest-json` project is rather defunct.  The developer/owner of `pytest-json-report` has this to say (under [Related Tools at this link](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-json-report/)).

> pytest-json has some great features but appears to be unmaintained. I borrowed some ideas and test cases from there.

The `pytest-json-report` project handles exactly the case that I'm requiring: capturing stdout from a subprocess and putting it into the JSON report.  A crude example of doing so follows:

```
import subprocess as sp
import pytest
import sys
import re

def specialAssertHandler(str, assertMessage):
    # because pytest automatically captures stdout,stderr this is all that's needed
    # when the report is generated, this will be in a field named "stdout"
    print(str)
    return assertMessage

def test_subProcessStdoutCapture():
    # NOTE: if you're version of Python 3 is sufficiently mature, add text=True also
    proc = sp.Popen(['find', '.', '-name', '*.json'], stdout=sp.PIPE)

    # NOTE: I had this because on the Ubuntu I was using, this is the version of
    # Python and the return of proc.stdout.read() is a binary object not a string
    if sys.version[0] == 3 and sys.version[6]:
        output = proc.stdout.read().decode()
    elif sys.version[0] == 2:
        # The other version of Python I'm using is 2.7.15, it's exceedingly frustrating
        # that the Python language def changed so between 2 and 3.  In 2, the output
        # was already a string object
        output = proc.stdout.read()

    m = re.search('some string', output)
    assert m is not None, specialAssertHandler(output, "did not find 'some string' in output")
```

With the above, using the `pytest-json-report`, the full output of the subprocess is captured by the infrastructure and placed into the afore mentioned report.  An excerpt showing this is below:

```
        {
            "nodeid": "expirment_test.py::test_stdout",
            "lineno": 25,
            "outcome": "failed",
            "keywords": [
                "PyTest",
                "test_stdout",
                "expirment_test.py"
            ],
            "setup": {
                "duration": 0.0002694129943847656,
                "outcome": "passed"
            },
            "call": {
                "duration": 0.02718186378479004,
                "outcome": "failed",
                "crash": {
                    "path": "/home/afalanga/devel/PyTest/expirment_test.py",
                    "lineno": 32,
                    "message": "AssertionError: Expected to find always\nassert None is not None"
                },
                "traceback": [
                    {
                        "path": "expirment_test.py",
                        "lineno": 32,
                        "message": "AssertionError"
                    }
                ],
                "stdout": "./.report.json\n./report.json\n./report1.json\n./report2.json\n./simple_test.json\n./testing_addition.json\n\n",
                "longrepr": "..."
            },
            "teardown": {
                "duration": 0.0004875659942626953,
                "outcome": "passed"
            }
        }
```

The field `longrepr` holds the full text of the test case but in the interest of brevety, it is made an ellipsis.  In the field `crash`, the value of `assertMessage` from my example is placed.  This shows that it is possible to place such messages into the report at the point of occurrence instead of post processing.

I think it may be possible to "cleverly" handle this using the hook I referenced in my original question `pytest_exception_interact`.  If I find it is so, I'll update this answer with a demonstration.